# HTTP Status code for functionality not implemented?

Tags: http, http-headers

This is a silly question, but I can't find any status code in http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6 that fits my need.

The thing is that I have an action `ChangePassword` that is only available if the login system is `MySql`. If you logged in via `LDAP/Active Directory`, it shows an exception "This method is not supported for your current user's backend".

I'm using `501 Not Implemented`, but I don't know if it's right based on its definition.

Comment: `501` is meant for unrecognized HTTP methods, not for missing server functionality. `ChangePassword` is not a standard HTTP method. What method are you using to send a `ChangePassword` action? A normal HTTP `POST` request, or a SOAP/REST request, or something else? Please provide more details.

Comment: Hi, changepassword is just a URL with web interface (called action in frameworks)

Comment: Any update? I'm going for a `404`